# Ever use anti-glare glasses for an over bright design department?

Tags: designers, work

My design department just moved to a new building and the space they set up for us is bright! Super bright! 16 in-ceiling fixtures with three tubes per fixture. The room is closed in, no windows and the walls are white. My eyes are killing me and I am starting to get headaches. All of our complaints are falling on deaf ears. The management won’t even let us just flick off the light switch. The glare off my monitors is incredible. There are 9 of us... Open revolt? Maybe...

Ever heard of any kind of glasses that would help with the brightness AND the glare?

Comment: You can check out Yellow Gunnar Glasses, I only have heard of them because of a gamer. I am sure there are other brands.

Comment: I personally have gunnar classes with two of the lense styles that they produce. The ones with the yellow tint and the clear lenses. I used to have a lot of eye fatigue and dryness issues. While I'd remmonend anyone with eye related issues to try them out, I don't see how they would help with bright lights in the room. If anything, they can increase the glare, depending on the lightning. Sun glasses maybe?

Comment: "The management won’t even let us just flick off the light switch." is the real problem here and maybe better suited for http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that a couple tubes from each light be removed. I've had great success with this request in the past. This way it still looks like the lights are on and the department is active, but it's not so bright it effects the workers. I'm assuming the lights are fluorescents... which are horrible. However, if management doesn't care you're kind of out of luck.

I have a couple pair of the Gunnar "computer" glasses... while nice, they don't help with brightness issues and the yellow one's are pretty unacceptable for anyone doing color work. I can't emphatically state they help or not. I've honestly not noticed much difference after a days work. Other than the bridge of my nose not being accustomed to glasses all day.

You might try a cheap monitor hood:

[image]